# Why is `vim -E` always exiting with non-zero exit code when using here-doc?

Tags: ex-mode, shell, posix

see the following session in dash:

```
$ printf "foo\nbar\n" > testfile
$ cat testfile
foo
bar
$ vim -E testfile <<-EOS
> 1
> s/foo/baz/
> x
> EOS
$ echo $?
1
$ cat testfile
baz
bar
$ vim -E testfile +'1' +'s/baz/foo/' +'x'
$ echo $?
0
$
```

I use ex-mode of vi for exchaning the string `foo` with the string `baz` by using a here-document. Apparently that works. But nevertheless vim is still existing with an exit code of `1`.

I then exchange the `baz` with `foo` again by giving the commands directly on the commandline to vim. That works too and returns with exit code of `0` (as expected).

What is the reason the here-document is always returning with an exit code of 1?

That even happens if I do not edit the file:

```
$ vim -E testfile <<-EOS
> 1
> p
> q
> EOS
foo
$ echo $?
1
$
```

What's going on there?

Comment: Does this also happen, when you call `vim --clean -E testfile <<EOF ...`? You could also try to run `vim -V9 -E testfile <<EOF...`. In my case the problem is produced by a BufWrite  autocmd that is not properly parsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a interesting question and I'm not sure I fully understand what is
going on. So here are *my* findings based on *my* Vim setup.

---

My setup contains some plugins (mainly self written) installed in `~/.vim/pack/.../start`. These plugins all require Vim to run in `nocompatible` mode (see `:help 'compatible'`).

I looked at two different scenarios:

1. run `vim -E testfile` and enter the commands manually
2. run `vim -E testfile <<-EOS...` with a here document as in your question

In the first case Vim exists with 0 in the second with 1.

By running scenario 2 with `-V9` I found that one of my plugins has an autocmd
for the BufWritePre event and that the code of the called function is not parsed
correctly. This error happens, as Vim is running in `compatible` mode.

From the verbose output of Vim I can see, that my `~/.vim/vimrc` is *not*
loaded, but all my plugins are loaded. This explains why vim is in
`compatible` mode.

Investigating scenario 1 shows, that my `~/.vim/vimrc` *is* loaded and hence
Vim runs in `nocompatible` mode. In that case everything works fine.

**Why is my `vimrc` only loaded in scenario 1?**

*My interpretation* is, that Vim detects that input is from a terminal. In that
case I could enter `visual` at the ex-prompt to switch to "normal" Vim. So Vim
is preparing for that.

In scenario 2 Vim detects, that input is *not* a terminal (it's the here-document)
and it is not possible to switch to visual. Even if you add `visual` to your
here-document, Vim will not switch to visual (it can't as it has no access to terminal input).

**Why are all the plugins loaded?**

To be honest: I don't know. I think that it is fair to assume, that most
plugins need Vim to run in `nocompatible` mode. So it doesn't make sense to
load them.

**Workaround**

In *my* case everything works smooth if I force Vim to run in `nocompatible`
mode by adding the option `-N`:

```
$ vim -N -E testfile <<-EOS
> 1
> s/foo/baz/
> x
> EOS
```

Comment: Yes! You are right! If I run vim with `--clean` or with `-u NONE` or with `-N` it is working correctly. It seems like your assumption is correct. When running with `-V9` I see that vim-yoink is adding an autocmd which may lead to that problem. I find this behaviour quite strange. I actually assumed that vim -E would start in compatible mode without parsing the .vimrc and without any plugins. It seems I was quite wrong. But your interpretation sounds very reasonable to me. Because I could switch to :vi it _is_ parsing the vimrc and loads the plugins.

Comment: Still, it doesn't make sense to me, since it is setting compatible mode. I still would expect that no vimrc would be read and no plugins loaded for the same reason, compatible is set.

Comment: I just tried with neovim and the behaviour is even worse! The have the same options `-e` and `-E`, but the behave differently and apparently have a different meaning! Additionally they introduced two other options `-es` and `-Es`. Honestly I don't really understand the difference between them. But I really dislike that they changed the behaviour of the existing options.

Comment: Vim has `-e` and `-E` and it supports `-es` and `-Es`. `-Es` is equivalent to `-E -s` and that means "extended ex-mode" and "silence". This is only mentioned in the man page of Vim, but not displayed with `vim --help`. Honestly I find the behavior around `-E` a little bit strange. You might consider to open an issue at Vims Github page.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
baz is here
```

Now, let's run two variations on your command:

```
$ vim -E file +'1' +'s/None/foo/' +'x'; echo code=$?
code=1
$ vim -E file +'1' +'s/baz/foo/' +'x'; echo code=$?
code=0
```

Apparently, the exit code is `0` if the substitute command succeeds in making a substitution and `1` otherwise.

Let's try this again but looking at the difference between `q` and `x` as a means of exiting:

```
$ cat file
foo is here
$ vim -E file <<-EOS
1
s/foo/bar/
q
EOS
$ echo $?
1
$ vim -E file <<-EOS
1
s/foo/bar/
x
EOS
$ echo $?
0
```

If a change was made to the file but vim was exited with `q` leaving the changes unsaved, the exit code is `1`.  If the changes were saved with `x`, then the exit code is `0` (success).  Using `q!` to exit while purposefully discarding changes, however, produces success (exit code `0`):

```
$ cat file
foo is here
$ vim -E file <<-EOS
1
s/foo/bar/
q!
EOS
$ echo $?
0
```